# Construct image with numpy.ndarray manually instead of cv2.imread()

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to understand how image is stored as RGB value

I just realized image that has been read by `cv2.imread()` method is just bunch of numbers especially RGB number stored in `numpy.ndarray` for every pixel when I check with builtin function `type()`

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('./rgb.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(type(im)) # Output: numpy.ndarray
```

But I still don't know what representation of each index in that array

To understand it, I want make `3col * 4row` image manually with numpy.ndarray

I expect image where:

- first column filled with red (255,0,0)
- second column filled with green (0,255,0)
- third column filled with blue (0,0,255)

for all rows!

Using `numpy.ndarray` declaration that stored in a variable for example `im` and successfully saved according what I expect

```
im = np.ndarray('What should I fill in here?')
cv2.imwrite('success.jpg',im)
```

Comment: Do `print(im.shape)`.  You should see something like `(480,640,3)`, which tells you there are 480 rows of 640 columns, where each column is an RGB triple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps.  I create an empty numpy array, then I fill each quadrant with a solid color:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = np.zeros( (480,640,3), dtype=np.uint8 )

im[:240,:320,:] = (255,0,0)
im[:240,320:,:] = (0,255,0)
im[240:,:320,:] = (0,0,255)
im[240:,320:,:] = (255,255,255)
print(im.shape)

p = Image.fromarray(im)
p.save('x.jpg')
```

Output:
[image]